# How to prevent Chrome from saving CSS changes?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, css

I have my Filesystem hooked up to Chrome, and I suppose that's why it's saving my CSS changes.

But I don't want it to.

***How can I tell Chrome to "forget" the changes I've made in the Styles pane?*** I don't want to rebuild my app to revert my CSS.

*<sub>Note: I have the cache turned off in the settings. **This is not a cache issue**, it is saving my CSS changes to my file.</sub>*

---

### *More Info*

For instance, I am using bootstrap, so I have a `form-group` class. Many sources are compiled to the final CSS, called `app.css`. form-group looks like this in the style pane:

[image]

Then I want to experiment with some changes and I do this:

[image]

It looks bad, and I want to start fresh, so I reload the page, but the rules I unchecked are still unchecked.

I have tried many things including closing the browser, and reopening my site in a new, completely different browser, and the changes still remain - the 2 rules are still crossed out.

Looking at the compiled `app.css`, you can see those rules have been commented out and saved:

[image]

How do I tell Chrome not to save my CSS changes?

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found - although you have to redo it every time you rebuild your app - is to ***Exclude the folder from the Filesystem*** folder in the Sources Pane.

The easiest way I found to do this is

1. Look at the CSS rule in the Style Pane, click on the css file:

   [image]
2. This will take you to the css file in the Sources Pane. Right-click on the file's tab and Click Reveal in Sidebar:

   [image]
3. Then it will show you the folder in the Filesystem pane. Right-click on that and select "Exclude Folder".